# Prevent Avogadro from clipping wavefunction plots

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, avogadro

When I try to plot wavefunctions in the Avogadro software I find that the orbitals are often clipped by a rectangular box. Does anyone know how to increase the size of this box so that I can plot larger orbital lobes?

Comment: This seems like a good question for the [Avogadro forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) - but in any case, it would help to know what version of Avogadro you're using and an example molecule or file.